# Inserir caminho do arquivo no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a necessidade de inserir um arquivo `.pdf` pela página e gravar no banco somente o caminho do arquivo. O usuário faz o upload e grava. O arquivo vai para pasta especifica e o banco MySQL somente fica com o path.

Segue o começo do projeto:

```
<?php
// Conexão e seleção do banco
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$con  = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass); // Marcando conexão
$db   = 'consultapagina'; // Marcando seleção
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or print mysql_error(); // Executando conexão e seleção

// Lendo os campos do .html
$link      = $_POST['link'];
$titulo    = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Codigo de inserção
$sql = "INSERT INTO pagina (link, titulo, descricao) VALUES ('$link', '$titulo', '$descricao')";

// Converte e Executa a query
$inserir = mysql_query($sql);

// Resultado para o .html
if ($inserir) {
    echo "Link inserido com sucesso!";
} else {
    echo "Não foi possível inserir link, tente novamente. Se o erro persistir contate o Administrador do Sistema.";
    // Exibe dados sobre o erro:
    echo "Dados sobre o erro:" . mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Como faço para gravar no MySQL o caminho quando o usuário clicar no gravar?

Comment: Ola, Willian. Qual seria sua duvida? Seria legal [edit] a pergunta e explicar onde está sua dificuldade, para que possamos ajudar. No link a seguir tem umas dicas de como melhorar a pergunta: **[Ask]**.

Comment: @Bacco eu editei a pergunta. A minha dificuldade já está no texto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui o que queria da seguinte maneira:

1º No HTML inseri:

```
<input name="arquivo" type="file" id="arquivo">
```

2º No PHP usei o código para salvar o arquivo em uma pasta especifica:

```
$nome_temporario=$_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
$nome_real=$_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];
copy($nome_temporario,"imagens/$nome_real");
```

3º E para salvar o caminho do arquivo no Banco mysql usei:

```
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']["name"];
```

Ai usar o $arquivo para o insert e pronto!

Código completo do PHP:

```
<?php
$nome_temporario=$_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
$nome_real=$_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];
copy($nome_temporario,"imagens/$nome_real");
// Conexão e seleção do banco
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass); // Marcando conexão
    $db = 'consultapagina'; // Marcando seleção
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or print mysql_error(); // Executando conexão e seleção

// Lendo os campos do .html
$link = $_POST['link'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']["name"];
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Codigo de inserção
$sql = "INSERT INTO pagina (link, titulo, descricao, arquivo) VALUES ('$link', '$titulo', '$descricao', 'imagens/$arquivo')";
// Converte e Executa a query
$inserir = mysql_query($sql);

// Resultado para o .html
if ($inserir) {
echo "Documento inserido com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível inserir link, tente novamente. Se o erro persistir contate o Administrador do Sistema.";
// Exibe dados sobre o erro:
echo "Dados sobre o erro:" . mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Como ninguém me ajudou tive que fazer muitas tentativas já que nunca trabalhei com php e mysql.

Mais venho aqui para deixar a solução da minha duvida e quem sabe siva para alguém.